# Colour of bear in Earth's surface

Tags: geometry, puzzle, spherical-geometry

A bear stands in one point of the Earth's surface. Walking one kilometer south , then walking one kilometer east and immediately after one kilometer north and reaches the point from which started.Find the color of the bear.

This is a question in a very old mathematical competition.I am confused because i can not think any mathematical way to approach it.Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Where *must* the bear live for that walk to even be possible?

Comment: It isn't very mathematical as far as the final answer goes.  I'm sure a search of the Web will result in the unraveling of this.

Comment: This is bearly related to mathematics.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are infinitely many solutions to this problem, all of which place the starting point either at the north pole, or very close to the south pole.  Hence the bear "must" be white.  Of course, real polar bears only live north of the Arctic circle, and they like to be near water, so they won't be anywhere near the north pole.  Hence the puzzle is biologically incorrect.

North pole: The circle exactly one mile away from the north pole has all its points one mile south of the north pole. The eastward walk is along this circle.

Infinite family: If the starting point is a bit more than a mile north of the south pole, then the one mile east will walk exactly $n$ circles around the south pole.  (by varying $n$ you can get infinitely many solutions)

Comment: In fact you get an infinite number of circles, *each* with an infinite number of points as a distinct solution...

Comment: Never thought of the south pole approach to this problem! Nice

Comment: I first encountered the south pole solution reading Larry Niven's "The Barsoom Project".

Comment: Regarding the south pole. Isn't it kind of hard to go further south from there? And if you start one kilometer from the south pole, going east has little or no meaning, and going north afterwards doesn't necessarily bring you back to the same point. So the infinite family is not really relevant, as I see it...

Comment: @holroy It does work. For example, if you start at any point $1 + \frac{1}{2 \pi}$ km north of the south pole, then walking 1 km to the east means walking once around the south pole in a circle with radius $\frac{1}{2 \pi}$ km.

Comment: @200_success... I didn't read the `a bit more than 1 km` part...

Answer (score 2):

The bear is white, (a polar bear) since the only possible point the bear started from is the north pole.